# How would this deadlock happens?

Tags: mysql, sql

Recently I am handing a SQL issue, I have two transaction, the transaction A first got the Next-Key Locks, and the transaction B tried to get the same lock, so it was waiting, then the transaction A tried to get Insert Intention Locks, so the deadlock happened. But I am confuse that why would this happens?

## Here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `changeset` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT',    
  `userId` int(10) NOT NULL COMMENT,    
  `documentId` varchar(20) NOT NULL,    
  `memberId` bigint(13) NOT NULL,    
  `createTime` bigint(13) NOT NULL,    
  `version` bigint(13) NOT NULL COMMENT,    
  `changesets` mediumtext,    
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),    
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq_documentId_version` (`documentId`,`version`) USING BTREE    
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=85771623 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

## And here is my deadlock log:

> (1) TRANSACTION:
>
> TRANSACTION 22640, ACTIVE 66 sec starting index read
>
> mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
>
> LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
>
> MySQL thread id 209, OS thread handle 123145559986176, query id 6204
>   localhost root Sending data
>
> `select * from changeset where documentId = '7oO5C_v' and version >=
>   13 for update`
>
> (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
>
> RECORD LOCKS space id 107 page no 15 n bits 704 index 
>   uniq_documentId_version of table `test`.`changeset` trx id 22640
>   lock_mode X waiting
>
> Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format;
>   info bits 0
>
> 0: len 7; hex 3976735431644a; asc 9vsT1dJ;;
>
> 1: len 8; hex 8000000000000000; asc         ;;
>
> 2: len 4; hex 051cbef7; asc     ;;
>
> (2) TRANSACTION:
>
> TRANSACTION 22639, ACTIVE 95 sec inserting
>
> mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
>
> 6 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 4 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
>
> MySQL thread id 212, OS thread handle 123145561657344, query id 6210
>   localhost root update `insert into changeset values (0, 9, '7oO5C_v',
>   814, 1, 13, 'x')`
>
> (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
>
> RECORD LOCKS space id 107 page no 15 n bits 704 index 
>   uniq_documentId_version of table `test`.`changeset` trx id 22639
>   lock_mode X
>
> Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format;
>   info bits 0
>
> 0: len 7; hex 3976735431644a; asc 9vsT1dJ;;
>
> 1: len 8; hex 8000000000000000; asc         ;;
>
> 2: len 4; hex 051cbef7; asc     ;;
>
> (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
>
> RECORD LOCKS space id 107 page no 15 n bits 704 index
>   uniq_documentId_version of table `test`.`changeset` trx id 22639
>   lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
>
> Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format;
>   info bits 0
>
> 0: len 7; hex 3976735431644a; asc 9vsT1dJ;;
>
> 1: len 8; hex 8000000000000000; asc         ;;
>
> 2: len 4; hex 051cbef7; asc     ;;
>
> WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)

Comment: Might also be handy for us to see the code that causes the deadlock? At the moment it looks like quite a simple "one transaction has started reading and another transaction is trying to write to the same data area being read"?

Comment: What is the isolation level? From the log, you have two long running transactions, the transaction is as simple as you described?

Answer (score 0):

Have you used "(nolock) " in your selects?

```
Select * From Table with (nolock)
```